# SQL selecting records from one table and using this as input to another table to delete records

Tags: sql, sybase, sql-delete

I have table1 with columns:

```
def_id, def_name, username etc
```

I have another table table2 which has some association:

```
assoc_id,parent_id,child_id
```

The parent_id , child_id are actually def_id's from Table1 . They get inserted into Table2 based on parent_child relation user action in GUI.

Now I want to select all def_id for a particular username from Table1 and then use that input to delete all the records if those def_ids are part of the parent_id or child_id from Table2.

How do I do this in SQL? I am using Sybase database.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Delete Table2
 Where parent_id In
     (Select def_id from table1
      Where username = @username) Or
     child_id In
     (Select def_id from table1
      Where username = @username)
```

Or

```
  Delete t2
  From table2 t2
  Where Exists
     (Select * From Table1
      Where def_id In 
          (t2.parent_Id, t2.child_Id))
```

Comment: Thanks all for the replies. Really thankfull for helping me out. Charles Bretana's first answer did the trick for me, the next query he suggested gave me a Syntax error 

SQL Anywhere Error -131: Syntax error near 'Where' on line 1

Thanks
-C

Comment: You may need to add a from clause to get the second one to work... I edited to show...

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is adding a subquery to the where clause.

```
DELETE ab
FROM AuthorArticle AS ab
WHERE ab.AuthID=(SELECT AuthID FROM Authors WHERE AuthorLastName='Yin')
```

Never used Sybase, but this is basic SQL and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELETE table2
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.def_id IN (table2.parent_id, table2.child_id)
```